# Looking for open source numerical solver

Tags: convex-optimization, constrained-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem

$$\begin{align}
&\min f(x)\\
&\text{subject to } Ax\leq b\\
&x \in R^{\sim 10000},\ b \in R^{\sim 10000}
\end{align}$$

$A$ is somewhat sparse (usually less than 5% populated) and I can efficiently evaluate $f(x)$ and $\nabla f(x)$. The Hessian of $f(x)$ comes at prohibitive computation times. $f(x)$ is a convex, non-linear, smooth function.

I tried Matlab's built-in solver `fmincon` but I keep receiving memory errors even though I am running on a system with 32GB memory. The exact Matlab settings I use are

```
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'GradObj', 'on','SubproblemAlgorithm', 'cg', 'Display', 'iter','Hessian',{'lbfgs',20}, 'MaxIter', 50, 'Diagnostics', 'on');
[x,fval] = fmincon(@(x)myObjFunc(x),x0,A,b,[],[],lb,[],[],options);
```

I would be very happy if someone could recommend a suited open source solver I could use for this problem -preferably with some Matlab interface- or even better: more elaborate settings for Matlab's `fmincon` to circumvent the memory issues.

I already found the `tomopt` package. However, this is not open source. In case I cannot find any open source alternative, I will check this out.

Comment: Can you get a "good" initial guess for $x$?

Comment: I can solve the problem without linear constraints $Ax \leq b$ considering only positivity on $x$ quiet efficiently. That would give a pretty good intial guess I think!

Comment: Did you tried [CPLEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.2.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1133.html), it can be used with MATLAB also.

Comment: As far as I understand, CPLEX is only applicable for linear and quad problems. I am interesting in general non-linear functions...

Comment: I have not more than 50 reputation to comment but I think you can have a look to this python's free tool [interalg](http://openopt.org/interalg).

Comment: It's somewhat surprising to me that you're running out of memory on a problem of this size.  What OS are you using (e.g. 32 or 64 bit, Windows, Mac OS, or Linux)?  What output do you get from the "memory" command?

Comment: Are you storing $A$ in memory as a sparse matrix or as a dense matrix?  If you write `whos A` in MATLAB, does it say that it is sparse (should be in the last column of the output)?

Comment: A is sparse and about 5% populated.

Answer (score 5):

[IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) is a good interior point method solver for convex nonlinear problems, and has a [MATLAB interface](http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node18.html), although I haven't used the MATLAB interface. (The solver, called from GAMS, is very good.)

[CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) is also a good package for convex problems, and [YALMIP](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Main.WhatIsYALMIP) is slightly more general; both of these packages provide a modeling language for posing nonlinear programs, which may or may not be what you want.

There's a whole host of open source optimization software under the auspices of the COIN-OR project, and if you're familiar with GAMS or AMPL, you might be able to use the NEOS server to submit your problem as a job and use the closed- and open-source solvers they have available.